# Can Intel CPUs change clock speed on a per-core basis?

Tags: cpu, overclocking, multi-core, turbo-boost, speedstep

Many multi-core Intel CPUs feature both [SpeedStep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) and [Turbo Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost), and can therefore run at clock speeds both below and above their base frequency.

Can these CPUs control the clock speed per-core, or does a single frequency apply to the whole processor?

In particular, when a tool such as [Intel Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20) shows the current clock speed of the processor, does this value apply to all cores or just some of them?

Comment: It would depend on the actual implementation and probably the actual CPU model/version of those technologies you're using.

Comment: Intel CPUs don't have this feature, I swear, I remember a question that asked a question similar to this one.. Some ARM CPUs do have this feature